# Python Attribute Error if statement

Tags: python, attributes, attributeerror

I have been working on this code for about a day now. A few hours on just this one part it keeps saying I have an attribute error on line 26. Unfortunately that is all the information I have. I have tried countless different ways to fix it and have searched many websites/forums. I appreciate any help. Here is the code:

```
import itertools
def answer(x, y, z):
    monthdays = {31,
                 28,
                 31, 
                 30, 
                 31, 
                 30, 
                 31, 
                 31, 
                 30, 
                 31, 
                 30, 
                 31}
    real_outcomes = set()
    MONTH = 0
    DAY = 1
    YEAR = 2

    #perms = [[x, y, z],[x, z, y],[y, z, x],[y, x, z],[z, x, y],[z, y, x]]
    possibilities = itertools.permutations([x, y, z])
    for perm in possibilities:
        month_test = perm[MONTH]
        day_test = perm[DAY]
        #I keep receiving an attribute error on the line below
*       if month_test <= 12 and day_test <= monthdays.get(month_test):
            real_outcomes.add(perm)

    if len(realOutcomes) > 1:
        return "Ambiguous"
    else:
        return "%02d/%02d/%02d" % realOutcomes.pop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `monthdays` does not have a `get()` method, and that is because `monthdays` is a `set`, not a `dict` as you probably expect.

Looking at your code it seems that a list or tuple would be appropriate for `monthdays`. A set is not useful because it is not ordered and can not include duplicates:

```
monthdays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

and then:

```
if month_test < len(monthdays) and day_test <= monthdays[month_test]:
```

---

Your code suggests that you eventually will want to handle years. In that case you should look at the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module. It provides function [`monthrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) that gives the number of days for a given year and month, and it handles leap years.

```
from calendar import monthrange

try: 
    if 1 <= perm[DAY] <= monthrange(perms[YEAR], perm[MONTH])[1]:
        real_outcomes.add(perm)
except ValueError as exc:
    print(exc)    # or pass if don't care
```

Comment: Just a quick question, why wouldn't be a dict? +1

Comment: @PythonMaster: because that is the syntax for declaring a `set`. A dictionary contains keys _and_ values, not just values.

Comment: I actually just changed it to a dict and it works perfectly! as I said I'm a bit new to python. I am also going to try a version with the code you gave. I appreciate the help! I thought the colon would have spliced it instead of set a key

Comment: @TrevorMurphy: you can use a dictionary, however, you are simply emulating a list by using the list indices as dictionary keys. Having said that, a dictionary might be better because you can map the month days to 1-based keys (which you are probably using), resulting in more readable code.

Answer (score -2):

set objects ('monthdays' in your case) don't have attribute 'get'

you should iterate over it or convert it to list, e.g.:

`list(monthdays)[0]` will return the first item of the resulting list

Comment: A set can not contain duplicates, and there is no inherent order. Thus iteration or conversion to a list will not be helpful.

Comment: what does my snippet have to do with duplicates and inherent order? I am just showing how he can get items from it

Comment: try running your code and you should see the problem that I raise.

Comment: The point is, @Bob, that the OP wants the number of days for each month. However, `monthdays` is a set, so it will actually look like this: `set([28, 30, 31])`. Converting that to a list with `list(monthdays)` gives `[28, 30, 31]`. How will the OP determine from this the number of days in June? Similarly iteration does not help either because it will merely iterate over the 3 items in the set. That's why I advised you to try your suggestion so that you may see the problem for yourself. Also, your answer is not useful, so I downvoted it too. Sorry, but that's how SO works.

Comment: And, if it was you that downvoted my answer, thanks a lot ;)